# How to count time on a disabled Button using java script code?

Tags: javascript, button

I have a Button in my project which is disabled for 5 seconds. I want to count time after each second (5,4,3,2,1 and 0) on the disabled Button instead of showing "Processing..." in the bellow code. How Is it possible?

java script:

```
    function lockoutSubmit(button) {
            var oldValue = button.value;
            setTimeout(function () {
                button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
                button.value = 'Processing...';
            }, 0)

            setTimeout(function () {
                button.value = oldValue;
                button.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }, 5000)
        }
```

html:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" 
                runat="server" 
                Text="Click Me" 
                onclientclick="lockoutSubmit(this)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For to show the seconds, you can to use this form.

- create the counter variable " i "
- create the setInterval function
- decrement the variable " i " inside the setInterval function
- drop the setInterval function inside setTimeout function.

  ```
     var oldValue = button.value;
     var i=5; //variable for to count the seconds
     var interval = setInterval(function () {
          button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
          i-=1;
          button.value = 'Processing '+ i +'...' ;
      }, 1000)

      setTimeout(function () {
          clearInterval(interval); //drop the interval
          button.value = oldValue;
          button.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }, 5000)
  ```

I hope help you :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is not a good practice of doing such thing. If your progress finishes before 5 sec then you put your clients on hold for nothing. If it couldn't finish after 5 sec then youre gonna be enabling button again before the right time. What you need to do is listen for a callback for whatever you're doing on that button click and when the process actually ends enable that button again.

Anyways what you asked for in OP can be done like this:

```
function lockoutSubmit(button) {
    var oldValue = button.value;
    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);

    var sec = 5;
    button.value = sec;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        sec--;
        button.value = sec;
        if (sec <= 0) {
            button.value = oldValue;
            button.removeAttribute('disabled');
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

You can forget the first `setTimeout` then you need to do `setInterval` instead of SetTimeout since you want the sec to be shown step by step. In that interval you're gonna decrease the sec value and check if it reaches zero and if it does enable the button again with the default value.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/58z6koz1/3/)

Comment: But this does not allow Button click event execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setInterval` function instead of `setTimeout`. The difference between those functions is that setInterval execute the function every X milliseconds until `clearInterval` is called.

```js
function lockoutSubmit(button) {
  var oldValue = button.value;
  var value = 5;
  button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  button.value = value;
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    value--;
    if (value < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      button.value = oldValue;
      button.removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
      button.value = value;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="lockoutSubmit(this)"/>
```

I hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use the setInterval and clearInterval functions instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval

```
function lockoutSubmit(button) {

    var oldValue = button.innerHTML,
        countdown = 5,
        intervalID;

    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    button.innerHTML= 'Processing...';

    intervalID = setInterval(function(){
        if(countdown===0)
        {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            button.removeAttribute('disabled');
            button.innerHTML = oldValue;
        }
        else
        {
            button.innerHTML = countdown--;
        }
    },1000);
}
```